# Can anyone improve on the below Fuzzyfind function for VBA?

Tags: algorithm, vba, function, find, fuzzy-search

This function lets you find similar strings from a range without having to do an exact search.

The formula looks like this: =FuzzyFind(A1,B$1:B$20)
assuming the string you are performing a search for is in A1
and your reference or options table is B1:B20

The code is here:

```
Function FuzzyFind(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant
For Each cell In tbl_array
  str = cell
  For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
    If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
      a = a + 1
      cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid(cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
    End If
  Next i
  a = a - Len(cell)
  If a > b Then
    b = a
    Value = str
  End If
  a = 0
Next cell
FuzzyFind = Value
End Function
```

The results from this function are hit and miss. Can anyone improve the intelligence of this algorithm?

Thank you :)

Comment: Just to be correct the goal is to find the cell that contains the most of a particular values? Example Cat,Battle ...when looking for t, battle has more ts, so return Battle ? Also is everything in the same case? or do we need to worry about that

Comment: Everything is upper case. And your example is correct
Suppose our word to search for is "apple"
suppose the strings in our table are 
bag produce,
onions,
giant peaches,
electronics and downloadable applications,

It would probably return electronics and downloadable applications due to "app" the string with the most in a row matches

Comment: I am not understanding this line : a = a - Len(cell)

Comment: I got confused with that too. I think it counts the matches between our string and the value in the cell then it trims excess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, I think it will find the best match

```
Function FuzzyFind2(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant
Dim Found As Boolean

b = 0
For Each cell In tbl_array
  str = cell
  i = 1
  Found = True
  Do While Found = True
    Found = False
    If InStr(i, str, lookup_value) > 0 Then
        a = a + 1
        Found = True
        i = InStr(i, str, lookup_value) + 1
    End If
  Loop

  If a > b Then
    b = a
    Value = str
  End If
  a = 0
Next cell
FuzzyFind2 = Value
End Function
```

Comment: How does it improve on the original? Can you walk be through it briefly?

Comment: @JohnsonJason When I was using the original one it pretty much always came back with the first one it found. This one comes back with the one with the most concurrence, I think the above answer is probably better

Comment: @ Holmes IV I switched this to best answer as it returned better results than the Levenshtein approach. Although for the example he gave above comparing names in a data base I think the Levenshtein approach would be best. However, in my situation, your fuzzyfind2 rocks. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what "FuzzyFind" entails, but this is a VLOOKUP that uses the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to find similar data.

The Levenshtein distance lets you select a "percentage match" that you can specify instead of the typical `TRUE` or `FALSE` from a normal VLOOKUP:

Usage is: `DTVLookup(A1,$C$1:$C$100,1,90)` where 90 is the Levenshtein Distance.

`DTVLookup(Value To Find, Range to Search, Column to Return, [Percentage Match])`

I typically use this when comparing names that come from different databases like:

```
Correct Name    Example Lookup  Percentage Match    Other Report
John S Smith    John Smith      83                  John Smith
Barb Jones      Barbara Jones   77                  Barbara Jones
Jeffrey Bridge  Jeff Bridge     79                  Jeff Bridge
Joseph Park     Joseph P. Park  79                  Joseph P. Park
Jefrey Jones    jefre jon       75                  jefre jon
Peter Bridge    peter f. bridge 80                  peter f. bridge
```

Here's the code:

```
Function DTVLookup(TheValue As Variant, TheRange As Range, TheColumn As Long, Optional PercentageMatch As Double = 100) As Variant
If TheColumn < 1 Then
    DTVLookup = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If
If TheColumn > TheRange.Columns.Count Then
    DTVLookup = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Exit Function
End If
Dim c As Range
For Each c In TheRange.Columns(1).Cells
    If UCase(TheValue) = UCase(c) Then
        DTVLookup = c.Offset(0, TheColumn - 1)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf PercentageMatch <> 100 Then
        If Levenshtein3(UCase(TheValue), UCase(c)) >= PercentageMatch Then
            DTVLookup = c.Offset(0, TheColumn - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
Next c
DTVLookup = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function

Function Levenshtein3(ByVal string1 As String, ByVal string2 As String) As Long

Dim i As Long, j As Long, string1_length As Long, string2_length As Long
Dim distance(0 To 60, 0 To 50) As Long, smStr1(1 To 60) As Long, smStr2(1 To 50) As Long
Dim min1 As Long, min2 As Long, min3 As Long, minmin As Long, MaxL As Long

string1_length = Len(string1):  string2_length = Len(string2)

distance(0, 0) = 0
For i = 1 To string1_length:    distance(i, 0) = i: smStr1(i) = Asc(LCase(Mid$(string1, i, 1))): Next
For j = 1 To string2_length:    distance(0, j) = j: smStr2(j) = Asc(LCase(Mid$(string2, j, 1))): Next
For i = 1 To string1_length
    For j = 1 To string2_length
        If smStr1(i) = smStr2(j) Then
            distance(i, j) = distance(i - 1, j - 1)
        Else
            min1 = distance(i - 1, j) + 1
            min2 = distance(i, j - 1) + 1
            min3 = distance(i - 1, j - 1) + 1
            If min2 < min1 Then
                If min2 < min3 Then minmin = min2 Else minmin = min3
            Else
                If min1 < min3 Then minmin = min1 Else minmin = min3
            End If
            distance(i, j) = minmin
        End If
    Next
Next

' Levenshtein3 will properly return a percent match (100%=exact) based on similarities and Lengths etc...
MaxL = string1_length: If string2_length > MaxL Then MaxL = string2_length
Levenshtein3 = 100 - CLng((distance(string1_length, string2_length) * 100) / MaxL)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this theme a lot and definitely Holmes IV answer is the best. I would just add a small update to compare always in uppercase. For my problems it recommended me more accurate options.

```
Function FuzzyFind3(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant
Dim Found As Boolean

b = 0
For Each cell In tbl_array
  str = UCase(cell)
  i = 1
  Found = True
  Do While Found = True
    Found = False
    If InStr(i, str, UCase(lookup_value)) > 0 Then
        a = a + 1
        Found = True
        i = InStr(i, str, UCase(lookup_value)) + 1
    End If
  Loop

  If a > b Then
    b = a
    Value = str
  End If
  a = 0
Next cell
FuzzyFind3 = Value
```