# Excel VBA: Weighted Jaccard Similarity (Fuzzy Lookup)

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I'm working on a project that involves a lot of data clean-up and combining like data.

The data I'm working with includes an Account Name and Address Information (Address 1, Address 2, City, State, Zip Code). I've been using the Excel Fuzzy Lookup Add-In to locate like records greater than or equal to a 90% Similarity Threshold. I'm ready to move forward with automating my process, but, unfortunately, there isn't any way to access the Add-In via VBA.

I've found a number of different functions (Weighted Damerlau-Levenshtein, Jaro-Winkler Similarity, etc), but none of them seem to be as accurate as the Microsoft Add-In. Since the Add-In uses Weighted Jaccard Similarity, I'm wondering if anyone has found or developed a function to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have some test data I can try it with? I wrote a `VLOOKUP` function that uses Levenshtein distance and lets you use a percentage match parameter instead of the standard true/false parameter. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30903011/1274820

Comment: I do have test data, but I'm unable to share. I would need to put together a set of dummy test data. I used the following Levenshtein Distance Function (reworked for VBA) and did not have good results: https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/909002-levenshtein-approximate-string-matching